# assign different value to nonzero element in rows of dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

For example, I have dataframe xx, which has n1 rows and n2 columns. I have a vector X has n1 elements. Is there a function that can assign the corresponding elements of X to the nonzero elements of each row of dataframe xx? That is to say, after this process, all the nonzero elements in each row will have the same value.

I know for loops can do this. But I wonder is there a function that can do this?

Here is an example:

```
xx = data.frame(x = c(0, 1, 0, 2, 3), y = c(0, 1, 3, 0,2), z = c(1, 0, 1, 3, 1)) 
X = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

I want some function, that can produce a data.frame like

```
xxOut <- data.frame(x = c(0, 2, 0, 4, 5), y = c(0, 2, 3, 0,5), z = c(1, 0, 3, 4, 5))
```

Comment: It does not work. Your code only work for a vector. What I want is to do this for a data.frame.

Comment: Read [MCVE]. Post a small example that allows testing and demonstration.

Comment: You should be using a matrix, not a data.frame: `X * (xx != 0)`. Also, you should probably not be doing this. No additional info is conveyed this way over a 1/0 or TRUE/FALSE matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following method, also base R will also work.

```
xx[xx !=0] <- rep(X, length(xx))[xx !=0]
xx
  x y z
1 0 0 1
2 2 2 0
3 0 3 3
4 4 0 4
5 5 5 5
```

Comment: Thank you! Very neat and easy to understand.

Answer (score 4):

A way via base R,

```
xx[] <- lapply(xx, function(i) mapply(function(z, j) replace(z, z != 0, j), i, X))
> xx
#  x y z
#1 0 0 1
#2 2 2 0
#3 0 3 3
#4 4 0 4
#5 5 5 5
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a third solution.

```
newx <- split(xx, 1:nrow(xx))

do.call(rbind, mapply(FUN = function(n1, n2) {
  n1[n1 != 0] <- n2
  n1
  }, n1 = newx, n2 = as.list(X), SIMPLIFY = FALSE))

  x y z
1 0 0 1
2 2 2 0
3 0 3 3
4 4 0 4
5 5 5 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option using `sweep`

```
xx[] <- sweep(!!xx, 1, X, `*`)
xx
#  x y z
#1 0 0 1
#2 2 2 0
#3 0 3 3
#4 4 0 4
#5 5 5 5
```